# SQLAlchemy retrieve one-to-many entities by subquery

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

How can I instruct SQLAlchemy to load one-to-many relations? I could join them, but this causes duplicates and (depending on the size of the result) a lot of overhead. Ideally, I would like to modify `session.query` in a way so that multiple (two) queries are sent retrieving the parents and all their children entities. How is this possible by either configuring SQLA or extending the session class? Or maybe this is not the usual way of doing things in SQLA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-to-many relationship is usually done by making a list attribute in Parent (,,one'') class and parent_id backreference in Child (,,many'') class (Please look here: [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html)).

So you generally create Parent class:

```
class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = "parents"
  dbid = Column(Integer, Sequence("parent_seq"), primary_key=True)
  children = relationship("Child", order_by = "Children.dbid", backref = "_parent")

  def __init__(self, children = [])
    self.children = children  #remember to initialize children as list!
```

And Child class:

```
class Child(Base):
  __tablename__ = "children"
  dbid = Column(Integer, Sequence("child_seq"), primary_key=True)
  parent_dbid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.dbid"))
```

If you want to add child to parent, just do it like that:

```
p = Parent()
c = Child()
p.children.append(c)

session.add(p)
session.add(c)
session.commit()
```

Then if you want to load parent with all of its children you just load parent with `session.query(...)` and **children are loaded automatically-you don't have to make any joins** unless you want to for example load only parents whose children have specific attribute values.

Hope that helps. Please write comment if anything is unclear-I will try to edit my answer to specify.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How many queries would SQLA send to retrieve all children from multiple parents?

Comment: It depends on your database structure and probably what DB engine you're using. The easiest way to check is to enable printing all queries that SQLA makes. You can do this while creating engine: `engine = create_engine("path_to_your_database", echo = True)`. Then create session like this: `Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)` and `session = Session ()`. P.S. If you like my answer please accept it ;).

Comment: SQLA seems to be querying the children for each parent by default. The behaviour can be modified by adding a `lazy` parameter to the relationship field (see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/loading.html#using-loader-strategies-lazy-loading-eager-loading).